# Hide/mask tomcat from open access

Tags: tomcat, java

How to mask tomcat app adress from public access easily. Let's say we run it on default port 8080.

So myapp.com:8080 is easy to scan, whatever port we use it's no problem. Lockoutrealm that tomcat java offer is ok but I need to hide it from world.

I was thinking about putting very long adress name of app: myapp.com:8080/alsdfjkdslfjkldfjkdjfakdsjfskljfdskfjalkfjlkfjkldsjf2342343243434

Nobody will guess it, not possible in real. If you have better method of masking please let me know.

Comment: If you're going to copy/paste from another SE site please at least clean it up.

Comment: What you mean by copy paste? It's my post.

Comment: See the content I edited out.

Answer (score 1):

What you are proposing is considered "security by obscurity". While it does provide a modicum of protection, it is not real security.

Consider the following:

- Implement firewall rules that block traffic from any IPs except those which need to access the application
- Ensure that you are using a secure method of authentication for your application.
- Implement request rate limiting rules. This will help prevent brute-force attacks on your application.
- **Use HTTPS**

Comment: http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/ looks interesting, do you know any good examples of request limiting rules? Will mod_qos or mod_security work with tomcat?

Comment: You will need to open another question on that.

Comment: But you must admit that this obscurity is hard to bypass. 30 (or more) characters link is not possible in real life to guess in normal reasonable time manner. AFAIK tomcat hasn't got any leaks or legal methods to get webapps paths. Only method is to know that or brute forcing adresses.

Answer (score 0):

Use tomcat's remote [host](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Host_Filter) / [address](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Filter) valves.